# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: PUSH0

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

While deploying my smart contract, I keep getting this error:
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [invalid opcode: PUSH0

```
import solcx
solcx.install_solc('0.6.0')
from solcx import compile_standard
import json
from web3 import Web3
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()



with open ("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()
    print(simple_storage_file)


compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    #solc_version="0.6.0",
)
#print(compiled_sol)
with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

#get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"]["bytecode"]["object"]

#get abi
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]
print(abi)

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://goerli-rollup.arbitrum.io/rpc"))
chain_id = 421613
my_address = "0xc80e5761af132995BecefD637**************"
private_key = "0x1d70b76bc2**********************"

#Create contract in Ganache
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

#Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_address)
print(nonce)

#Build a transaction
#Sign a transaction
#Send a transaction

#transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().build_transaction({"chainId" : chain_id, "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,"from" : my_address, "nonce": nonce})
print(w3.eth.gas_price)
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().build_transaction(
    {
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "gasPrice": 900000000,
        "from": my_address,
        "gas": 100000,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
print(transaction)
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
print(private_key)
print(signed_txn)



tx_hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ
Lesson 4

This is my solidity file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    // This is a comment!
    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;
    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
    
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of going back to an older version of Solidity compiler, in hardhat to prevent use of `PUSH0` you can try setting `evmVersion` to a previous version (e.g. `paris`, which is the one before `shanghai`) whilst still using the latest compiler version (0.8.21 currently):

```json
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: `0.8.21`,
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 15000
          },
          evmVersion: `paris`
        }
      },
    ],
  },
```

Polygon announced last week that they’ve just implemented `PUSH0` on their zkEVM blockchain. I’ve tested the testnet and it works. zkEVM mainnet will work from 2023-09-10: [Polygon zkEVM: Dragon Fruit Upgrade (with New Opcode) Coming to Mainnet Beta](https://polygon.technology/blog/polygon-zkevm-dragon-fruit-upgrade-with-new-opcode-coming-to-mainnet-beta)

I also tested 140 blockchains today and only found these ones (16%) that support `PUSH0` currently:

- auroraTestnet
- edgeware
- edgewareTestnet
- gnosis
- chiado
- goerli
- mainnet
- moonbaseAlpha
- moonbeam
- moonriver
- polygonZkEvmTestnet
- pulsechain
- pulsechainV4
- sapphire
- sapphireTestnet
- scrollSepolia
- sepolia
- syscoin
- syscoinTestnet
- taikoTestnetSepolia

Hopefully the many other blockchains will follow, as developers want to be able to use the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

`PUSH0` is a new op code that was added with the Shanghai EVM update: https://www.evm.codes/#5f?fork=shanghai

Some chains have not yet included the new op code.

The tutorial and and solidity version you are using are quite old. I suggest you target an earlier version of the EVM by updating your compiler settings with the following:

```
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "evmVersion": "paris", # Add this line
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    #solc_version="0.6.0",
)
```

You might also want to look at increase the solidity version for your contracts.

You can read more about compiler settings here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/using-the-compiler.html